# multiprocess communications using message queue

Tags: c, linux, fork, message-queue

I'm trying to implement a program similar to this example:

the program passes an integer among 4 processes and each process decrements the integer

each process have its own mailbox

Each process check its mailbox for variable "counter" and if it was found it will decrements it

Then it send the counter  variable to the next process

but there is a bug in the program and I cant find it.
note that this an assignment and Im just looking for tips that helps me find the bug.

[image]

```
typedef struct {
    int counter;
    char data[256];
    int id; //id of the process that previously decremented the counter
} msg;



int main(int arqc, char *argv[]){
    int key=9;
    int id=0;
    pid_t  pid;
    int num=5;
    int    i, k;
    int arr[5];


    //create 5 forks
    if (arqc !=  2){
        num=5;
    }else{
        int ret = sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &num);
        if (ret != 1)return 0;
    }
    for(i=0 ; i<num ; i++){
        if ((pid = fork()) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "can't fork, error %d\n", errno);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (pid == 0) {
            id=i;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }



    //process 1 to n comes here
    msg m;
    int boxid = msgget(id, 0600 | IPC_CREAT);
    arr[id]=boxid;
    int firstRun=1;

    //initiate the first move
    if((id==0)&&(firstRun==1)){
        m.counter = INIT_COUNTER;

        //send msg to next process
        msgsnd(arr[id], &m, sizeof(msg), 0); //send msg to own inbox
        firstRun=0;
    }



    while(1){
        //check inbox of current process
        int rec = msgrcv(arr[id], &m, sizeof(msg), 0, 0);

        printf("Im %d, counter is %d, rec is %d\n",id, m.counter, rec);


        int index;
        if(id==num){
            index=0;
        }else{
            index=id+1;
        }

        //send message to the next inbox
        int sent = msgsnd(arr[index], &m, sizeof(m), 0);

        printf( "Error opening file: %s\n", strerror( errno ) );

        sleep(1);
    }

}
```

Comment: "there is a bug" is a vague statement. As Alexander said, you have to provide more detail on what you've tried to do to solve the problem. At a minimum, you should provide some thought as to what you think could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial `msgsnd` is failing with an invalid argument and everything get munged from there on.

SysV message queues require a message type field as the first field in a message so you need to do something like this.

```
typedef struct
{
    long int  mtype;
    int counter;
    char data[256];
    int id; //id of the process that previously decremented the counter
} msg;
```

You also have to set the message to something and set the correct length before you send it.

```
//initiate the first move
if ((id == 0) && (firstRun == 1))
{
    m.mtype = 100;
    m.counter = INIT_COUNTER;
    strncpy(m.data, "some kind of message is nice", sizeof(m.data));
    m.id = id;

    size_t msgsize = sizeof(msg) - sizeof(long int);

    //send msg to next process
    int sent = msgsnd(arr[id], &m, msgsize, 0); //send msg to own inbox

    if (sent == -1)
    {
        perror("msgsend");
        exit(1);
    }

    firstRun = 0;
}
```

You run into problems beyond this (e.g. set the correct size on the `msgrcv`s) but this should get you over the initial hump.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is unreasonable to expect the SO crowd to *just solve* the (homework?) problem for you without any effort on your side. It is unclear *what* the problem is, *how* the program behaves currently, and what steps were made to debug it.

Rants aside, I'd recommend cutting out all the steps leaving only two participants and getting it to work in that simple configuration. Once it works, add another one, make sure it still works and so on.